# Modified Copying

Tags: shell

Is there anyway by i can copy files of a directory recursively by checking if the file already exist in the destination (specifically by using cksum command) during the copy procedure??

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called rsync. It's typically used across a network but also works locally.